# Python module working on 2.7 but not on 3.5

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

Here is my code :

## `Animals/__init__.py`

```
from Mammals import Mammals

from Bird import Bird
```

## Animals/Mammals.py

```
class Mammals(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.members = ['Tiger', 'Elephant','Wild Cat']

    def print_members(self):
        for member in self.members :
            print('this is a member :' + member)
```

## Animals/Bird.py

```
class Bird(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.birds = ['sparrow','robbin','duck']

    def print_members(self):
        print('printing birds in bird class')
        for bird in self.birds:
            print('this is a bird '+ bird)
```

## test.py

```
from Animals import Mammals, Bird

mam = Mammals()
bird = Bird()

mam.print_members()

bird.print_members()
```

I have installed Python 3 (MacOSX) and I am using it with virtualenv. This code works fine with 2.7, but it doesn't work with python3.5. It always gives `ImportError: No module named Mammals`

Comment: And it is Animals/__init__.py

Comment: `from .Mammals import Mammals` a dot is missing here. The command `2to3` will do that for you.

Comment: @thanks a lot. Got the issue fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Python 3 makes a distinction between relative and absolute imports, dropping support for implicit relative imports.

Your code runs in python2 because the parser implies relative imports for `Birds` and `Mammals`, but python3 stops doing this.

Run `2to3` for your files will fix it.

```
from .Mammals import Mammals
from .Bird import Bird
```